Stolen gold, and they almost get away with it
This might have been a TV movie, probably from the 1970s.
It was about a gang of thieves attempting to steal bars of gold. They are successful, but part of the plan is to leave the gold in a truck that is to remain parked until they return to the city in several months.
At the end of the movie it seems like they are going to get away with it, until the truck is rear-ended and the bumpers locked. A helpful policeman tries to uncouple the bumpers, but since the truck is full of the gold, it is too heavy. He opens the back and there is the gold and a couple of thieves.

What's with the close votes?  This seems like a very clear and detailed question!

This is the The Alpha Caper, an 1973 TV movie starring Henry Fonda.
You can watch it here:



Near the end of the movie, starting ca. at 1:09:00, you can see the scene you describe in your question above: truck bumped, tow truck lifts the van, rear doors open, gold bullions fall onto the road, two of the robbers are inside the van.
Police car bumps into the van:

Rear doors burst open, gold falls out:

Two robbers hiding inside:

